# Elasticsearch best match sorting mechanism by counting highlights and amount of elements in arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 7.6 and I am trying to figure out a way to sort my results by the best match based on the search query.

There are two parts for this and I will try to explain, but first I'll provide a demo structure of the data mapping:

```
    "handles" : {
      "properties" : {
        "references" : {
        },
        "value" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

So we have `handles`, and we have 4 more properties with the same mapping as `handles` which are: `summary`, `contact_details`, `motives`, `interests`.

The system must search on `handles.value.keyword` and so on for rest of the properties.

Now there are two types of best match mechanisms:

**Catalog**

A catalog is when you access the page and you did not search anything yet, the system will fetch best match results without a search query, and this is the strategy:

Any property out of the 5 available properties that contains atleast 1 element in the array, will increase the score by 1:

This example is only for `handle` to prevent this post to be too long:

```
  "query": {

    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                double score = 0;
                if (doc['handles.value.keyword'].size() > 0) { 
                  score += 1;
                
                }
                return score;
              """
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "max"
    }
  },
```

This works perfectly.

However my problem is with the second mechanism.

**Best match based on query**

Now when you insert a query, I will still increase the score when each property has atleast one element in the array, but I also want to increase the score every time an element in any of the 5 properties is highlighted (full match or wildcard match).

For example if I found 3 matches:

1. **handles.value**: `['ben', 'ben10', 'car']`, **interests.value**: `['ben']`
2. **handles.value**: `['car', 'ben', 'ten']`
3. **handles.value**: `['car', 'ben']`, **interests.value**: `['ben']`

And my search query was `ben*`, the best matches sort will be:

`1, 3, 2`

Since 1 contains 3 highlights it will be the first, 3rd contains 2 highlights it will be sorted as the second, and 2nd will be 3rd because it contains one highlight.

**Now what is the problem?**
Elastic sort functions does not have the context of the returned highlights, so I have no idea to know what values were fully/wildcard matched so I can't really count. Maybe I could loop through all elements in the script and check if the element contains the query string in it, but that probably will be very unstable because I have more than 2 million items and may be even more.

example:

```
          for(handle in doc['handles.value.keyword'])
          {
            if(handle.value.toString().contains('ben'))
            {
              score += 2;
            }
          }
```

Is there a proper way to do such scoring mechanism in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

The first part (Catalog) doesn't require any scripts. It can be done with a simple exist query inside a boolean query. The second part is trickier. Most of the queries that handle wildcard don't count number of matched terms. However, if you are always using prefixes in your search something like `match_phrase_prefix` with custom similarity might work.

```
DELETE test

PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "similarity": {
      "scripted_tf": {
        "type": "scripted",
        "script": {
          "source": "doc.freq"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "handles" : {
        "properties" : {
          "value": {
            "type": "text",
            "similarity": "scripted_tf",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "interests" : {
        "properties" : {
          "value": {
            "type": "text",
            "similarity": "scripted_tf",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"handles.value":["ben","ben10","car"],"interests.value":["ben"]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"handles.value":["car","ben","ten"]}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"handles.value":["car","ben"],"interests.value":["ben"]}

// Catalog Query
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "handles.value"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "interests.value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

// Best match based on query

GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "handles.value"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "interests.value"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "handles.value": {
              "query": "ben"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "interests.value": {
              "query": "ben"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you can clarify what you expect users to type, I might be able to adjust this example to better match your use case.